How to define a Fortran Module across several files/Subroutines?
I work with Fortran projects in VS2019.
I've been advised to put the subroutines into a MODULE to get more help from the debugger and code check.
My project employs many subroutines, 50 or more, with each subroutine in a different file.
It would be impractical to put all those subroutines into a single file.
How can I define a module that includes those subroutines?

Why is it impractical for your 50 subroutines to be in a single file?

How do the various subroutines interact with each other?

@Echeban You are aware that a program can have more than one module?

You could use INCLUDE to include the source for each subroutine into the CONTAINS section of the module. You'd want to make sure that the separate source files were not compiled as part of the build - you could do that by selecting all those files in the project, right click, and change "Exclude file from build" from No to Yes.

When you mindlessly include all the source into a contains section, how do do then cope with subroutines no longer being external subroutines?

@francescalus this matters only if you don't then add USE of the module in places that are needed. It would not be required if references are within the included procedures. You do have a point that simply including everything and calling it a day isn't going to work, but in many cases, wrapping internally-used procedures in a module is a workable process.

When you submit your code for review, you are near the start of a conversation, not at its end.
If you get a comment like

put the subroutines into a module

your first step should be to understand what is meant by that, not to jump to implementing that.
Yes, a module procedure is "better" than an external procedure in many (many) ways, such as helping your compiler and other tools check your code and debug errors. An obvious question, though, is "which module?".
Stuffing all subroutines, in some way, into a single module is not the default expectation of a comment which advises the use of modules. Work out how your subroutines work, what the interactions are between the subroutines and the things using them, and between one subroutine and another.1
There's no simple answer. Look at your code, understand what module procedures are, understand the benefits of using modules for your code, and then worry about how to define the various modules which are required. And after that, how to use the subroutines which are now module procedures not external procedures.
When designing your module(s), consider associations and data sharing which may exist between the subroutines.
If it's "impractical to put all those subroutines into a single file", consider submodules.
Don't forget, get further advice from the person who has volunteered time to look at your code and has experience and expertise to offer.

1 If you blindly stuff all your subroutines into a single module, your code may suddenly fail to work. That's surely not the desired goal of code review.
